# Yii2 widget rendering (Redactor, translation not working)

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, redactor, yii-widgets

I am having trouble getting translations to work.

[https://imperavi.com/redactor/ Version 3, Yii 2.0.12, PHP 7.1.16]

Here is my code in yii2 (php framework):

```
use yii\easyii\widgets\Redactor;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
...

<?= $form->field($model, "content")->widget(Redactor::className(),[
'options' => [
        'id'=>"redactor",
        'minHeight' => 200,
        'imageUpload' => Url::to(['/admin/redactor/upload'], true),
        'buttons' => ['html', 'formatting', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', 'alignment', 'horizontalrule', 'link', 'image', 'file','clips'],
        'plugins' => ['fontcolor', 'fontfamily', 'fontsize', 'table','clips','filemanager','imagemanager','alignment','fullscreen','video','widget'],
        'maxHeight' => 500,
        'placeholder' => 'Skriv inn, eller lim inn kopiert tekst og/eller bilder her..',
        'toolbarFixed',
        'lang' => 'no',
        'clickToEdit' => true,
        'clickToCancel'=> ['title'=> 'Avbryt'],
],
])->label(false) ?>
```

Here is what it generates:

```
jQuery('#notes-content').redactor({
    "imageUpload":"http://byggmannkalk.no/admin/redactor/upload",
    "fileUpload":"/admin/redactor/upload","id":"redactor",
    "minHeight":200,
    "buttons":["html","formatting","bold","italic","deleted","unorderedlist","orderedlist","outdent","indent","alignment","horizontalrule","link","image","file","clips"],
    "plugins":["fontcolor","fontfamily","fontsize","table","clips","filemanager","imagemanager","alignment","fullscreen","video","widget"],
    "maxHeight":500,
    "placeholder":"Skriv inn, eller lim inn kopiert tekst og/eller bilder her..",
    "0":"toolbarFixed",
    "lang":"nb",
    "clickToEdit":true,
    "clickToCancel":{"title":"Cancel"},
    "imageUploadErrorCallback":function(json){alert(json.error);},
    "fileUploadErrorCallback":function(json){alert(json.error);}
});
```

The language files gives me a console error:

```
VM2426:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opts' of undefined
    at eval (eval at globalEval (jquery.js?v=1523865201:343), <anonymous>:2:13)
    at eval (eval at globalEval (jquery.js?v=1523865201:343), <anonymous>:74:3)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.js?v=1523865201:343)
    at text script (jquery.js?v=1523865201:9208)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery.js?v=1523865201:8243)
    at done (jquery.js?v=1523865201:8707)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js?v=1523865201:9123)
    at XMLHttpRequest.send (catcher.js:197)
    at Object.send (jquery.js?v=1523865201:9175)
```

Which points to my language file:

```
(function ($) {
    $.Redactor.opts.langs['nb'] = {
        html: 'HTML',
....
        filename: 'Filnavn (valgfritt)',
        edit: 'Endre',
        center: 'Midten'
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Is it possible to modify my creation of the redactor instance so that it adds it to $ and not just to the for $('#notes-content')?**

Is there a parameter I am missing?

The language file(s) will be used many places throughout the program where Redactor is used so I do not desire to modify them.

Thank you kindly for any help.

Ps. I noticed on the demo site (https://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/language/translations/) that they had modified the language file:

```
(function($R)
{
    $R.lang['fi'] = {
...
        "redo": "Redo"
    };
})(Redactor);
```

Comment: are you sure the option is accessed via `$.Redactor.opts.langs['nb'] ` and not `$.Redactor.options.lang='nb'`, and i think you need to include that language file too see here https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/get-started/languages/

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thank you for your help. When I console.log($.Redactor); it is undefined. I need help in 'adding' Redactor to '$' or modifying my language files to target Redactor correctly.